# ReactJS - timeouts not completeing, set within loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with the below code to trigger a flash when fields change.  All is well, except that my timeouts are not actually completing due to some javascript magic i do not understand.  If anyone can shed light on why these timeouts would not be completing that would be very helpful - thanks!

I'm assuming it has something to do with using `this` inside of the loop?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const updates = {};
  fields(this.props).forEach(f => {
    if (!_.isEqual(this.props[f], prevProps[f])) {
      updates[updatedKey(f)] = true;
    }
  });
  if (Object.keys(updates).length > 0) {
    this.setState({ ...updates });
    Object.keys(updates).forEach(f => {
      const tkey = timeoutKey(f);
      clearTimeout(this[tkey]);
      this[tkey] = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ [updatedKey(f)]: false }), 700);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by timeouts not completing? I suspect it is going in an infinite loop somehow.

Comment: Yeah so if it was an infinite loop then the page would freeze due to rerendering, unfortunately it's not the case. The timeouts are set and the variables hold the timeout id afterwards but if i set a breakpoint in render then it never actually gets called after the timeout is set, as it should since the function passed to timeout should change the state. My updated attributes never get set to false and stay true.

Comment: calling `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` will trigger an infinite loop

Comment: What does `updatedKey` function returns?

Comment: It will not. Only if done without a proper conditional. @nikksan

Comment: @Prakash Sharma it returns the field with Updated concatenated to it.

Comment: Unfortunately the component does not handle the change of the fields, so it's forced to detect the change when passed in. It is a presentational component.